# Como inserir o nome dos arquivos carregado no banco de dados

Tags: php, codeigniter

```
$this->load->library('upload');

    //Configure upload.
    $this->upload->initialize(array(
        "upload_path"   => './public/uploads/album/',
        "allowed_types" => 'mp3',
        "max_size" => '2194304000',
        "overwrite" => 'FALSE'
    ));

    //Perform upload.
    if($this->upload->do_multi_upload("files")) {


        $arr = array(

                'fx_title' => ?????,
                'alb_id'  => $id,
                'user_id'  => $user_id

        );

        $this->db->insert('nmp3_faixas', $arr);
    }
```

Qual seria o código que retornaria os nomes dos arquivos carregados, e gravaria no banco de dados ? Estou usando a class https://github.com/stvnthomas/CodeIgniter-Multi-Upload

Comment: Ta na documentação https://github.com/stvnthomas/CodeIgniter-Multi-Upload#get_multi_upload_data get_multi_upload_data(): retorna um array com informações dos arquivos carregados dai você trata esse array e manda para o banco.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sempre procure primeiro na documentação:

```
$this->load->library('upload');

//Configure upload.
$this->upload->initialize(array(
    "upload_path"   => './public/uploads/album/',
    "allowed_types" => 'mp3',
    "max_size" => '2194304000',
    "overwrite" => 'FALSE'
));

//Perform upload.
if($this->upload->do_multi_upload("files")) {

    // Retorna detalhes dos arquivos enviados
    $upload_info = $this->upload->get_multi_upload_data();  

    // Inicia o array dos dados que serão inseridos
    $arr = array();

    // Varre o array com info. dos arquivos
    for ($i=0; $i < sizeof($upload_info); $i++) {

        // Nome do arquivo em cada elemento
        $fx_title = $upload_info[$i]['file_name'];

        // Adiciona no array para inserir no banco
        $arr[] = array(
            'fx_title' => $fx_title,
            'alb_id'  => $id,
            'user_id'  => $user_id
        );

    }

    // Insert all into db
    $this->db->insert_batch('nmp3_faixas', $arr);

}
```

**get_multi_upload_data()**

A biblioteca estendida também vem com um método get_multi_upload_data () que irá retornar os dados sobre cada arquivo enviado como um array multi-dimensional.

https://github.com/stvnthomas/CodeIgniter-Multi-Upload#get_multi_upload_data

Comment: Deu certo, porém se carrego vários arquivos, retorna apenas o primeiro.

Comment: Qual a sua saída de print_r($upload_info); ?

Comment: sim, fiz exatamente como está aí

Comment: Veja se funciona (vide edit), ele varre o array acumula os dados e insere no banco.

Comment: O seu código parece perfeito, mas o problema ainda persiste dessa vez tenho o erro no banco de dados Unknown column 'fx_title' in 'field list'

Comment: Ele esta dizendo que a coluna `fx_title` não existe na tabela `nmp3_faixas` que você informou.

Comment: Realmente, errinho bobo que não percebi, na tabela estava fx_titulo em pt, e não percebi. De qualquer maneira obrigado, está funcionando agora. ;)